# Item pairing between two .txt

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary

I have been trying to combine or pair two text files.
One file contains User:Key
The other file contains Key:Pass
I want a 3rd text file created containing the corresponding pairs of User:Pass based on the key matching.
Here is what Ive tried most recently

```
    Private Sub Rotate()
    Dim Cracked() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text)
    For Each lineA In Cracked
        TextBox5.Text = lineA
    check()
    Next
End Sub
    Private Sub check()
    Dim toCheck() As String = TextBox5.Text.Split(":")
    Dim tHash As String = toCheck(0)
    Dim tPass As String = toCheck(1)
    Dim lines1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox2.Text)
    For Each line In lines1
        If lines1.Contains(tHash) Then
            Dim toAdd() As String = line.Split(":")
            Dim uHash As String = toCheck(0)
            Dim uUser As String = toCheck(1)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(uUser + ":" + tPass)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
     Public Sub CopyListBoxToClipboard(ByVal ListBox2 As ListBox)

    Dim buffer As New StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        buffer.Append(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
        buffer.Append(vbCrLf)
    Next

    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(buffer.ToString)

End Sub


Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    CopyListBoxToClipboard(ListBox1)
    End Sub
```

The delimiter changes but for now the : works.
I tried splitting and matching but either the textbox5 does not rotate or it rotates through the list and thats all.

Comment: Your question mentions creating a third text file, but nowhere in your code is there something that would create or write to a text file.  Please re-phrase this question, or include more of your code.

Comment: @nicko fixed. Simple copy and paste or I could save to filepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Dim KeyPassFile As String = "..."
Dim UserKeyFile As String = "..."
Dim UserPassFile As String = "..."

Dim KeyPass As New Hashtable

' Read Key:Pass file 
For Each Line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(KeyPassFile)
    Dim iStart = Line.IndexOf(":")
    Dim Key = Line.Substring(0, iStart)
    Dim Pass = Line.Substring(iStart + 1)
    KeyPass.Add(Key, Pass)
Next

' Create User:Pass file
Dim OutFile = IO.File.CreateText(UserPassFile)

' Read User:Key file
For Each Line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(UserKeyFile)
    Dim iStart = Line.IndexOf(":")
    Dim User = Line.Substring(0, iStart)
    Dim Key = Line.Substring(iStart + 1)
    If KeyPass.ContainsKey(Key) Then
        ' We have a match for the key, write it to the file
        OutFile.WriteLine(User & ":" & KeyPass(Key))
    End If
Next

OutFile.Close()
```

This will probably not work for very large files that doesn't fit in memory, and there is no duplicate check for the key insertion in the hashtable, but I'll leave something for you to do.. :)

Also, in your code, you read the file specified in the `TextBox2.Text` as many times as there are lines in the `TextBox1.Text` file..

Comment: I was wondering if I was :( Thank you for pointing that out. Going to try this out now.

Comment: I tried "If Not Keypass.contains(key) Then, IDK What Im doing wrong

Comment: I can see the logic behind it but cant get it to write anything in the .txt

Comment: NVM, guess the list was just that big. Thank you